# Is there a way to kill a certain number of turtles within a radius of a patch with a certain color in Netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I am very new to Netlogo and I am trying to simulate culling of turtles within a certain region based on the characteristics of the patch. Within my model landscape, I have one single patch that is orange. I want 50% of turtles within 5 pixels of that patch to die. I would also like this process to continue every year after the first year of the simulation (this part I think I have).  Can anyone help me?

```
if d = 10 [
if year >= 2 [
let ring nobody
set ring patches in-radius 5 patches with [pcolor = orange]
ask turtles-on ring [die]
]
]
```

Answer (score 0):

`in-radius` reports agents that are within a certain distance from the caller, so the orange patch must be the one calling `in-radius`.

The code in your example is not reproducible, so I'll make an arbitrary example:

```
to setup
  clear-all

  ask one-of patches [
    set pcolor orange
  ]

  create-turtles 100 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
  ]
end


to go
  ask patches with [pcolor = orange] [
    ask turtles-on patches in-radius 5 [
      if (random 2 < 1) [die]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Note that `in-radius` reports agents within a certain distance, where the unit of measure of distance is a patch`s side.

Identifying patches within a certain distance and then asking all turtles on those patches to die (as in the example above, which follows the approach in your question) has a different effect than asking all turtles within a certain distance to die.

Which of the two approaches fits your case is something that you have to decide. Below, the code that would address turtles directly:

```
to go
  ask patches with [pcolor = orange] [
    ask turtles in-radius 5 [
      if (random 2 < 1) [die]
    ]
  ]
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it.

Comment: The code you suggested worked perfectly. However, I don't want the radius to wrap the world, so I tried using in-radius-nowrap instead of in-radius, but for some reason it is still wrapping the world. Have you ever run into this?

Comment: @MirandaStrasburg I am not able to reproduce the problem. To have more meaningful answers, you should provide a [mre] (this is true always, even for your initial question). Anyway, which version of NetLogo are you using? The [Dictionary for NetLogo 6.2](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#) does not contain the `nowrap` primitives, and the [User Manual](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/NetLogo%20User%20Manual.pdf) recommends removing them and changing the topology of the world instead.

Comment: @MirandaStrasburg Anyway, if for some reason you want the world to wrap except for this computation, it looks like the `nowrap` primitives are stll working. I have checked it on a small example I made and I see that `in-radius-nowrap` works as expected, so I am not able to help you further without having more elements. This is why it is useful that you provide a reproducible example in your question, when you have an error or an unexpected result,